# Non-additivity of higher order terms in the intermolecular potential

Tags: statistical-mechanics, potential-energy, many-body, born-oppenheimer-approximation

The intermolecular potential energy can be written as

$$u(r_{1},...,r_{N})=\sum_{i<j}^{N} u_{2} (r_{i},r_{j}) + \sum_{i<j<k}^{N} u_{3} (r_{i},r_{j},r_{k})+...$$

where the nuclear coordinates are $r_{1},...,r_{N}$. Only the first term for the pair interactions is called additive. Why is this the case? How are the higher terms non-additive, and what are the implications?

Comment: What is the definition of additive here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no established naming convention.

Usually, in this context, additivity of the n-body terms of the interaction energy means that the presence of an additional group of particles implies just summing the new interaction terms to the previous ones without modifying them. In general, this is an approximation since the interionic or interatomic interactions depend on the electronic degrees of freedom, and their elimination in favor of an interatomic potential usually implies an irreducible many-body interaction not decomposable in two-body, three-body, etc. interactions.

A more accurate naming is to speak about *pair-wise* additivity, *three-body additivity*, and so on.